# How to add network image in pdf in flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, flutter-plugin

> Hello guys, I was trying to add network image in the pdf. The pdf is
> created using **printing: ^5.5.0** plugin . I am getting run time
> error. Please help out, Thanks in advance.

**previewpage.dart**

```
    
      final pdf = pw.Document();
    
      MemoryImage images = [];
    
      Future _getImage() async {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          var response = await http
              .get(Uri.parse("image url here"));
          final image =
              pw.RawImage(bytes: response.bodyBytes, width: 50, height: 100);
          images.add(image);
        }
        _writeOnPdf();
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

> using printing: ^5.5.0

```
try {
            final provider = await flutterImageProvider(NetworkImage(
        "https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*ilC2Aqp5sZd1wi0CopD1Hw.png"));
            images.add(provider);
    } catch (e) {
            print("****ERROR: $e****");
            return;
    }
    
    pw.Center(
            child: pw.Padding(
            padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(3),
            child: pw.Image(
              images[i],
              width: 50,
              height: 100,
             ),
           ),
          )
```